# Fields of a payment method not displaying when switching between payment methods

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I have made a block in admin panel for my custom module, where I am giving option to the admin user for selecting a payment method while creating a quote . For this I have copied the payment method selection form from the Magneto's default form that it uses to give pay method selection.

This is working fine and selecting a method. But the problem is suppose I select the credit card method, in magento order creation page, it shows fields to enter card details etc. But here in my quote creation page, it's just switching the pay method but not showing any further fields of the selected payment method.

Am I missing anything in the form, which I have copied from magento order creation part?

EDIT:: The problem is `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('payment.method.' . $_code) ?>` is not loading. Any ideas to solve this please?